# Looking for PHP MySQLi Login script

Tags: authorization

I am looking for a PHP MySQLi Login script where a user can only access tasks assigned to them by admin.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Building a login script is very easy but if you are writing the code you should be trying it out for yourself. This is the logic :-
Registration
Allow user to select a username and a password.
Check your database using a SELECT query or a mysqli_num_rows function to see if the username is unique(that is why many systems use email addresses since, by virtue of the system, they are unique.)
If the username does not exist, insert into database.
Use a validation email system to check if email really exists(assuming you are using an email as a username)
Login
Allow user to insert username/password into a form.
Check if unique combo exists, if it does allow a session to begin to grant individual user experience to login user
 Else
Send them packing for trying to gain access to non-public info(or whatever).
Ps:- you should encrypt the username/password combo. A simple algorithm is sufficient, eg:- string_replace('@', 'something to replace it with, your variable);

Answer (score 0):

The most secure and professional and easy to use and free source code is here
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

There is a tutorial and step by step guide to use on your site